# Exercise 4.16 in Brezis' Functional Analysis (Counterexample)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

The exercise 4.16 in the Brézis book - Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDE's, is as follows:

Let $1<p<\infty$. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^p(\Omega)$ such that

(i) $f_n$ is bounded in $L^p(\Omega)$.
(ii) $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. on $\Omega$.

1. Prove that $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ weakly $\sigma(L^p,L^{p'})$;
2. Same conclusion if assumption (ii) is raplaced by

(ii') $\|f_n - f\|_1\rightarrow 0$.

3. Assume now (i), (ii), and $|\Omega|<\infty$. Prove that $\|f_n -f\|_{q}\rightarrow 0$ for every $q$ with $1\leq q<p$.

**My question:** Is it possible to build a sequence satisfying (i), (ii), and $|\Omega|<\infty$ and $\|f_n -f\|_q \not\rightarrow 0$ for $q=p$, i.e. $\|f_n -f\|_p \not\rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure take $f_n(x)=\sqrt n$ for $x<\frac  1 n$ and $0$ for $x \geq \frac 1  n$. Take $f=0$ and $p=2$.

Comment: Is there any additional hypothesis for the convergence to be valid in case $p=q$?

Comment: If $|f_n| \leq g$ $\forall n$ with $\int |g|^{p} <\infty$ then $\|f_n-f\|_p \to 0$. @VictorHugo

Comment: I just had one question, why $f_n \not\rightarrow 0$ in $L^2(0,1)$? @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @VictorHugo $\int |f_n|^{2}=1$.

Comment: I still can't see why this is the result, $\int_{0}^{1} |f_n(x)|^2dx=\int_{0}^{1/n} \frac{1}{n} dx+\int_{1/n}^{1} 0dx=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Wouldn't that be it?

Comment: @VictorHugo Sorry, I should have taken $f$ to be $\sqrt n$ on $(0,\frac 1 n )$ I have edited the answer.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murphy Could you take a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790685/prove-that-fx-int-x-10x-1-cdots-int-x-n0x-n-fy-dy)? You always have good ideas for this kind of problem.